# merge all the elements in a list python

Tags: python

I have a list of string like:

```
s = [("abc","bcd","cde"),("123","3r4","32f")]
```

Now I want to convert this to the following:

```
output = ["abcbcdcde","1233r432f"]
```

What is the pythonic way to do this?
THanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
>>> [''.join(x) for x in s]
['abcbcdcde', '1233r432f']
```

Comment: A list comprehension is better than my map+lambda. +1

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> map(''.join, s)
['abcbcdcde', '1233r432f']
```

That should do it

Comment: Nice... my use of lambda is unnecessary.

Comment: Hehe ya there is no need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
output = []
for grp in s:
    output.append(''.join(grp))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> map(lambda x: ''.join(x), s)
['abcbcdcde', '1233r432f']
```

Comment: If you're going to use `map`, use it the way jamylak does, directly on `''.join`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, just want to check, what about reduce and operator.add, i read that in such a way both of them would perform quite fast and effective, or i am wrong?

```
s = [("abc","bcd","cde"),("123","3r4","32f")]

from operator import add

[reduce(add, x) for x in s]
```

Comment: Adding strings in a loop takes quadratic time.